# jquery increment checkout number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a span field that has a number generated by counting items in a session array. when a user adds an item to the cart I need to increment this value by 1. I've tried the parseInt function but it doesn't seem to work. console shows the id is being selected. Just can't seem to increment by 1.

jQuery code is:

```
var checkout_number  = parseInt($('#checkout-count').html());
console.log(checkout_number); // Shows value 2 etc
```

upon success increment by current checkout_number by 1:

```
$.parseInt($("#checkout-count").val(),10) + 1;
```

Any help would be great

Comment: In jquery, there is nothing like $.parseInt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you're not actually incrementing the HTML value of the `checkout-count` element - try this instead:

```
// use the HTML of the checkout-count span as the current checkout number
var checkout_number = parseInt($('#checkout-count').html(), 10);
// replace the HTML of the checkout-count span with the old value plus one
$('#checkout-count').html(checkout_number + 1);
```

Comment: use .text() instead of html() for more optimized solution!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `parseInt` function to adding the value in jquery

```
var checkout_number = parseInt($('#checkout-count').text(), 10);
$('#checkout-count').text(checkout_number + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this this works fine.

```
$('#checkout-count').text(parseInt($("#checkout-count").text()) + 1);
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7279dk20/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#checkout-count').text(function() {
    return +(this.innerHTML) + 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="checkout-count">2</span>
```